# Download multiple files from a page using javascript and jQuery in firefox extension

Tags: javascript, jquery

I developed a Firefox extension where downloads multiple files from a page by triggering on different anchors with different links.

What I did in javascript with jQuery:

```
var $tr = $("tr");
var downloadLinks = [];

$.each($tr, function() {
    var tds = $(this).find("td");

    var name = tds.eq(1).find("span");
    var text = name.text();

    if (text.match(/\.Update\./gi)) {
        return true;
    }

    downloadLinks.push(tds.eq(2).find("a"));
});


if (downloadLinks.length > 0 && confirm("Found " + downloadLinks.length + " items to be downloaded. Download them now ?")) {

    for (var i = 0; i < downloadLinks.length; i++) {
        var $a = downloadLinks[i];
        var url = $a.prop("href");

        if (url.indexOf("http") < 0) {
            url = windows.location.protocol + "//" + windows.location.host + "/" + $a.prop("href").trim('/');
        }

        $a.prop("href", url);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $a.get(0).click();
        }, 800 * (i + 1));
    }
}
```

The problem is that only **last** item is downloaded `downloadLinks.length` times. If length is 20 then last item is downloaded 20 times.

Where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a is the problem here, when time out is fired $a is equals to the last object read by the loop.

try with:

```
setTimeout(function(j) {
            var $a = downloadLinks[j];
            $a.get(0).click();
        }, 800 * (i + 1), i);
```

this should work.